# Plotly move subplots same direction

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, subplot

I'm writing a code in plotly with two scenes, but I want to move them at the same time when I drag one them. How can I do this?

This is a code sample, but it isn't useful for what I'm asking. I just want to be able to move both at the same time.

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, cols=2,
    specs=[[{"type": "scene"}, {"type": "scene"}]])

fig.add_scatter3d(x = [1,2,3], y = [1,2,3], z = [1,2,3], mode='lines', 
                  name="Border 1", 
                  line=dict(
                      width=8,
                      color='goldenrod',
                      ), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_scatter3d(x = [3,2,1], y = [3,2,1], z = [1,2,3], mode='lines', 
                  name="Border 4", 
                  line=dict(
                      width=8,
                      color='mediumseagreen',
                      ), row=1, col=2)

fig.update_scenes(aspectmode='cube')

fig.show()
```